# Do I need multiple masters on OKD?

Tags: openshift-origin, okd

So I have a question regarding setting up OKD for our needs - our team has already established that Kubernetes is basically the simplest way for us to manage our stack. We don't have too much workload; probably 3 dedicated servers could work through all of it, but we have a lot of services and tools that are best served by running in docker containers, and we also strongly benefit from running our fairly monolithic core application as a container to make deployment and maintenance simpler.

The question though, is that how many nodes we need; specifically, whether we need HA Master nodes.

From the documentation, it seems that Infrastructure nodes are responsible for routing. Does this mean that even if the master node goes down, the other nodes are still available and routing works, so long as domains point at the infrastructure nodes? Or would a failed master make all the other nodes unreachable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In our environment router pods are running on infra nodes and we can safely turn off master node without impact for applications.

- master node: api, controllers, etcd
- infra node: registry, router, metrics, logging etc.

With master turned off you just can't manage cluster, the rest works fine. It is good to have more than one master node for etcd redundancy, but with such small environment I think it makes no sense maintain more.

Comment: Thanks! Failover scenarios weren't clear from the docs, this helps a lot! 